# Usage of the word "Dialekt"

Tags: word-usage, idiomaticity

Consider the phrase

> … sprachen wie alle Einwohner des Dorfes *Dialekt* …

Would you say *sprechen mit einem Dialekt* or rather *sprechen Dialekt*?

PS: This is my first day on this stackexchange, in case I forgot some tags or used the wrong tags, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: The only feedback I'd give on the question is that it's usually best to include a whole sentence for context. The meaning is still clear in this case, but for future reference a single phrase may not be enough to get the intended meaning.

Comment: Fwiw, from experience living in Switzerland (Zürich canton), *Mundart* would be more commonly used in that context: `Mundart räde`; `Mundart reden`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are possible and correct. I would use either.

If I had to choose, "sprechen mit einem Dialekt" sounds a tiny tad, almost indiscernibly, more negative to my ears, in the direction of implying that the population isn't able to speak "proper" German, but only "German with a dialect".

"Sie sprechen Dialekt" is more parallel in grammar to "Sie sprechen Französisch" or "Sie sprechen Chinesisch", it values the dialect a bit more as a language of its own right.

Comment: As noted in the other answer, and particularly the comment to it, the prepositional use is, at least by some, considered incorrect, since a dialect is a form of language – something you speak, not something you speak _with_. This is in opposition to an accent, which is a phonetic ‘adjustment layer’ applied to whatever language/dialect is spoken, and **is** something you speak _with_; you can speak a dialect with an accent, but you cannot ‘speak with a dialect with an accent’. Conflating the two is common, but for learners, I would advise distinguishing them.

Answer (score 18):

"Dialekt sprechen" is correct, as well as "einen Dialekt sprechen".

"Mit einem Dialekt sprechen" doesn't sound quite right to me, as if you are confusing "Dialekt" and "Akzent".

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dialekt) confirms at least the correctness of "Dialekt sprechen".

Comment: Well put! The incorrect use of "Dialekt" (i.e. regional *language* variety) to mean "Akzent" (i.e. mere *phonology/phonetics*) is very common. Often this mix-up is evident, as in "Sie spricht gut Deutsch, aber mit einem spanischen Dialekt", which is a non-starter, since Spanish is not a regional dialect of German...